# Ruby on Rails - Get date - given is year, month, weeknumber and day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some troubles with the following task:
Given are the following parameters:

```
Year: 2016
Month: 2
Week of Month: 2
Day of week: Monday
```

The result should be `2016-02-08`

Is there a method to get this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code. Values used were supplied in the question `month = 2,` `week_number = 2` and `year = 2016`

```
month = 2
year = 2016
week_number = 2
FIRST_DAY = 1 #first day of every month
day = { monday: 1, tuesday: 2, wednesday: 3, thursday: 4, friday: 5, saturday: 6, sunday: 7}

first_wk_of_month = Date.new(year, month, FIRST_DAY).cweek  #=> 05
date_week_num = first_wk_of_month + (week_number - 1)   #=> 06

date = Date.commercial(year, date_week_num, day[:monday]).to_s # 2016-02-08
```

There are **52** weeks in a year and a month can have as low as 1 day in a week if it starts on Sunday. Taking that into consideration,

`first_wk_of_month` finds the week number in the year (between 1 and 52) on which the month in question starts.

`date_week_num` finds the actual week number in the year the date falls on. In this scenario which is 2nd week of February it returns `6` representing the 6th week of the year

Passing the `date_week_num` and the `day` to the `Date.commercial` allows us to find the `date`
Tested it with a couple of days and works fine. You could probably change the variable names. Hope this solves your challenge

Comment: Thank you very much Black Enigma!
This works very fine!

Comment: No problem, Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be

```
weekday_index = {monday: 1, tuesday: 2, wednesday: 3, thursday: 4, friday: 5, saturday: 6, sunday: 7}
day_in_a_week = 7
year = year_param # 2016
month = month_param # 8
week_number = 2
day_of_month = (week_number * days_in_a_week) - (days_in_a_week - weekday_index[:monday])
Date.new(year, month, day_of_month).to_s
```

Comment: Hi Sean. Thank you for the fast response. This is right, if the month starts with monday at 1. If i set the parameters to Month number 3 (March):
Year: 2016
Month: 3
Week of Month: 2
Day of week: Monday
day_of_month = 8 but should be 7